# Bullets trajectory

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need some some help. I'm working on game, and have problem with bullets trajectory. I have enemies and have player. Enemies and player can be positioned in random positions on screen. So when enemies are shooting in player, i need to have some formula to know the bullet trajectory. Bullet must move from enemy to player and move to out of screen bounds, in the same trajectory, like in others shooters. Can some one help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: If the bullet is slow, you can draw a dot in each time step. The effect will be somewhat similar to that in Angry Birds.

Comment: some bullets are slow, some are fast. I run bullets by CCMoveTo ....  so i need to have a destination point....

Comment: CCMoveTo moves object with straight lines. so it is no problem to find it's position in any time period

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I can't give you the code in the language you're looking for (don't have it to hand atm), I can explain the process. This requires a bit of trigonometry. Essentially, the most basic thing to do here is calculate the correct X and Y speed of the bullet to simulate "locking on". That can be achieved by working out the x and y distance between the player and enemy, the calculating (most likely using trig) the angle at which to fire, and then basing the xSpeed and ySpeed of the bullet on that angle.

When I first learned how to do this, I overlayed a triangle on top of the enemy which would indicate whether my trigonometry was correct by pointing directly to the player.

Hopefully understanding this process will give you a means to approach it!

There are also a lot of actionscript 3 tutorials on this which you could translate the logic from.

Good luck!